# Linkedin AdAnalytics Endpoint

Tags: python, linkedin-api

Working through the Linkedin Marketing AdAnalytics Endpoint - getting the following error with this URL and no documentation online as to why - anyone encounter this?

```
endpoint url =  'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&dateRange=(start:(day:1,month:1,year:2020))&timeGranularity=ALL&fields=impressions'
```

Error:

```
b'{"serviceErrorCode":3,"message":"Missing facet","status":400}'
```

If they mean add an account or campaign ID I did so below with encoded and not encoded and two errors below:

```
url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&dateRange=(start:(day:1,month:1,year:2020))&timeGranularity=ALL&fields=impressions&account=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:982225479'
```

error:

```
{"serviceErrorCode":0,"message":"Invalid query parameters passed to request","status":400}
```

encoded url:

```
url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&dateRange=(start:(day:1,month:1,year:2020))&timeGranularity=ALL&fields=impressions&account=urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredAccount%3A982225479'
```

error:

```
b'{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/account]","status":403}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Had the same error: "Invalid query parameters passed to request" I disabled  in the headers the "X-Restli-Protocol-Version" and the error desappeared

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo in your encoded URL. It should be 'accounts' instead of 'account'. Here you go:

```
url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&dateRange=(start:(day:1,month:1,year:2020))&timeGranularity=ALL&fields=impressions&accounts=urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredAccount%3A982225479'
```